# Unit testing a File.ReadAllText method

Tags: c#, .net, moq, xunit

Hi i'm learning to write tests with xUnit. I utilized System.IO.Abstractions in this class in order to use IFileSystem interface.

```
public class MyDictionary : IMyDictionary   
{
    IFileSystem _fileSystem;
    public MyDictionary() : this (new FileSystem()) {}

    public MyDictionary(IFileSystem fileSystem)
    {
        _fileSystem = fileSystem;
    }
    public Dictionary<string, string> GetDictionary()
    {
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>(_fileSystem.File.ReadAllText("dictionary.json"));
    }

}
```

Here is the test i wrote using Moq

```
    [Fact]
    public void GetDictionary_ShouldReturnDictionary()
    {
       using (var mock = AutoMock.GetLoose())
        {
            mock.Mock<IFileSystem>().Setup(x => x.File.ReadAllText("dictionary.json"))
                .Returns(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dic));

            var cls = mock.Create<MyDictionary>();
            var expected = dic;
            var actual = cls.GetDictionary();

            Assert.True(actual != null);
            Assert.Equal(expected, actual);

        }
    }

 Dictionary<string, string> dic = new Dictionary<string, string>
    {
        { "Key1",   "Value1" },
        {"Key2",    "Value2" }
    };
```

Is this ok?(the test works fine) Is there any other unit test i should write against this simple method? Testing for exceptions for example? If so how should i do it? Thanks in advance!

Comment: What have you written already?

Comment: This code is not really testable due to having a dependency on a specific file on disk.

If you wanted to split this out you would have to create an interface for handling the disk I/O that by default calls File.ReadAllText but in your unit test can be changed to a mock implementation. You would then pass this implementation in and expect that the method calls it correctly (and returns the expected results based on what the mock contains)